# RXJava. Continiously population of observable

Tags: java, javafx, rx-java

I have the following task:

I have some method `void populate(long id)` which must add `id` to some collection. This method called really often, so I want to 'buffer' some count of values and then populate collection. I have the following code snippet:

```
observable
        .observeOn(notFXThread)
        .buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())
        .observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())
        .subscribe(next -> next.forEach(resultList::addAll));
```

But I have 2 big problems:

1. I don't understand how I need to initialize observable.
2. I don't understand how I need to implement `populate` method.

I hope someone can help me.

**UPDATE 1:**
Obesrver don't know anything about id creation or caller. All is known for observer is how to populate and method, which must perform it.

Comment: I would say that you need to switch it around: have `populate` return the items directly, and have RxJava do the collection for you. However, that means that reactive streams must understand how the `id` is created and who calls your `populate` method. Can you add these in your question?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos, thanks for reply. I updated question for your terms. However, I already found the solution, but I'm not sure that post this right now is good idea (for reasons of increasing of my reputation by myself).

Answer (score 1):

I found solution in `PublishSubject` observable class, so solution for initializing looks as follows:

```
this.subject = PublishSubject.create();
this.subject
        .observeOn(scheduler)
        .subscribeOn(scheduler)
        .buffer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())
        .observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())
        .subscribe(result::addAll);
```

and `populate(long id)` method looks like:

```
public void populate(final Long id) {
    this.subject.onNext(id);
}
```

Each `this.subject.onNext(id)` call whole observable stack.

Comment: You do know that unless you have a very inefficient/badly-sized Collection implementation, the above block will take more time than the original, right?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos, I think I understand what you mean. In general, you are right, but I have some special point: each collection update generate real huge count of actions, which run in some specific thread (just 1 thread). So, when I need to populate collection by 4000 values the 'simple' implementation produce 4000 tasks for 1 thread. This thread simple is 'die'. In this implementation I decrease this count to something about ten times (I don't measure it, but I think ever more than 10 times).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that you were using JavaFx, I assume that's generating draw calls or somesuch? Yeah, buffering will help a lot! And re: answering your own question, remember this: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @TassosBassoukos, At-first, yes, collection for GridView (ListView). At-second, I really tried to find some solution but I was fail in this. If you know some links with solution of the same problem, I will be glad to add these to header of answer